# Is it possible to create custom keyboard in android which uses inbuilt dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary, autocomplete, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on building 3x4 layout keyboard for android and would like to know whether i can use system dictionary for auto-completion and suggestion for user input?
If it's possible please can you guide me?

Many thanks in-advance..

Comment: have you tried searching for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing built in dictionary is not permitted in non-rooted devices.